# Optimize Switch Case with C #

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Switch Case where I receive 6 different values, based on that value received every one for a fixed value defined by rule. I would like help to better this Switch Case, although it works I do not consider it to be well built or well formatted.

```
switch (IAP)
     {
        case 5:
            for (var c = 0; c < 5; c++)
                {
                    _query.NewCupon(doc, id, date);
                }
        break;

        case 6:
            for (var c = 0; c < 8; c++)
                {
                    _query.NewCupon(doc, id, date);
                }
        break;

        case 7:
            for (var c = 0; c < 11; c++)
                {
                    _query.NewCupon(doc, id, date);
                }
        break;

        case 8:
            for (var c = 0; c < 13; c++)
                {
                    _query.NewCupon(doc, id, date);
                }
        break;

        case 9:
            for (var c = 0; c < 16; c++)
                {
                    _query.NewCupon(doc, id, date);
                }
        break;

        case 10:
            for (var c = 0; c < 19; c++)
                {
                    _query.NewCupon(doc, id, date);
                }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a better fit for [codereview.se]

Comment: Dictionary with key as the element you ask in the switch case and value as the number to iterate in the for loop

Comment: Is the difference in each case really just the value of the case and the number of iterations of the loop (or just a simplification of the real difference)? Try using a switch expression to translate the case value to the iteration count. It'll be very compact: `int n = IAP switch { 5 => 5, 6 => 8, 7 => 11, 8 => 13, 9 => 16, 10 => 19, _ => -1 };`

Comment: @Igor when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". In the current form the code above would likely be closed as off-topic because it [is missing context](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3652#3652), which happens frequently on new posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of having the for loop in the switch statement, you can have the forloop outside and do something like this,

```
 IDictionary<int, int> numberNames = new Dictionary<int, int>();
   numberNames.Add(5,5);
   numberNames.Add(6,8);

    if(numberNames.ContainsKey(IAP))
    {
        for (var c = 0; c < numberNames[IAP] ; c++)
        {
            _query.NewCupon(doc, id, date);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Move your case logic to separate function with parameter how many times NewCupon should we called. For example:

```
case 10:
    GenerateNewCupon(doc, id, date, 19);
break;
```

Then at least you dont have duplicated code for using

```
_query.NewCupon(doc, id, date);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var IAP = 5;
            var iapDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>
            {
                { 5,5},
                { 6,8},
                { 7,11},
                { 8,13},
                { 9,16},
                { 10,19},

            };
            iapDictionary.TryGetValue(IAP, out int maxIndex);
            for (var c = 0; c < maxIndex; c++)
            {
                _query.NewCupon(doc, id, date);
            }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a good solution.